# Can you simplify this linq-to-entity groupBy query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

```
 List<int> types = Hospitals.GroupBy(h => h.TypeId, (key, group) => group.First())
                    .Select(t=> y.TypeId).ToList();
```

Trying to get the distinct type ids from the `List<Hospital>` objects. I'm not an expert in these linq querires and just want to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is the distinct TypeId fields, it's much simpler than that:

```
var types = Hospitals.Select(h => h.TypeId).Distinct();
```

Just a side-note on your original query: I often find that the method-style syntax of these operations is less readable than the query comprehension. It comes down to personal style, of course, but thus far I don't think I've ever written a GroupBy() or Join() in method syntax; to me this just flows better:

```
var types = from h in Hospitals
            group h by h.TypeId into types
            select types.Key;
```

Comment: Your answer is fine but I disagree about the query syntax. The basic `GroupBy()` is just the same as query syntax - `.GroupBy(h => h.TypeId)`. The question demonstrates one of the many `GroupBy` overloads... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx

Comment: Actually, I tend to find the query comprehensions easier to digest in most cases beyond simple Select() or Where() methods, but of course that's all just personal opinion.

Comment: I understand, & a lot of people prefer one over the other (I prefer method). I don't mind query syntax but it's apples and oranges when comparing the basic `group x by` with one of the more complication overloads using method syntax.